# Asynchronous File Upload in Play

Tags: playframework

How to implement Asynchronous File Upload using Play framework.

The question [Asynchronous File Upload in Java using Akka and Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198310/asynchronous-file-upload-in-java-using-akka-and-play-framework) is not answered by anyone.

Could you please share your thoughts on how to implement it?

I'm using angular as front-end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want something like this? https://dzone.com/articles/stream-a-file-to-aws-s3-using-akka-streams-in-play

Comment: i'm not an expert in scala. can u share a snippet in java as well as with exceptional handling to review